# Date in MON-YYYY format to Text format

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

How do I convert date format field to MON-YYYY format.

I have date 12-06-2014 and I want to compare it with JUN-2014.

Comment: Do you want to compare it with `01.06.2014` ? Or do you want to consider that `?-06-2014` is equal to `JUN-2014` ? I don't think that you need a text format. You can compare dates.

Comment: The frontend sends it in JUN-2014 or Jun-2014 format only.

Comment: I can try converting JUN-2014 to 06-2014 as well, if there is any format available.

Comment: Is this going to be English only?  The dd-mm-yyyy format is used globally.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a link that explains everything about date format:
[Date Format](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

Your solution is probably the following (MySQL version):

```
UPPER(DATE_FORMAT(yourDate, '%b-%Y'))
```

And for SQL Server:

```
UPPER(SUBSTRING(DATENAME(MONTH, yourDate), 1, 3) + '-' + CAST(DATEPART(YEAR, yourDate) AS VARCHAR(4)))
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: That returns a string value in the desired format. This query is for MySQL.

Comment: My bad. I needed this in SQL Server. DO you know if i can convert this query to SQL server one ?

Comment: I added the version for SQL Server, hope this will help you

Comment: @user1820973 Have you tried the SQL Server version? I tested it and it seems to return the desired value

Comment: Why `LTRIM(RTRIM(x))`? Is it because [you think] it's shorter than `CAST(x AS int)`? :)

Comment: @AndriyM It's just a short way to cast and trim a numeric value into a `VARCHAR` value.

Comment: That's what I thought and my point was that CAST would be slightly shorter (by one character). However, if you used just RTRIM or just LTRIM, it would certainly be shorter than CAST. You don't need to use both in this situation.

Comment: Note that RTRIM would be shorter only in typing. In execution, it would do what CAST does *plus* attempt to trim any trailing spaces. That's a very tiny amount of work, but it might be worth keeping in mind for cases where performance is crucial.

Comment: @AndriyM `RTRIM` and `LTRIM` functions automatically make the conversion to `VARCHAR`, if you first cast the `INT` value into `VARCHAR` you'll also need to trim the result.

Comment: *Need* to trim the result of conversion of an `int` to a `varchar`? You mean `CAST(x AS int)` results in `x` enclosed in spaces?

Comment: @AndriyM The expected result is to concat the month name with the year value, the cast as `INT` is useless because function `DATEPART` automatically returns an integer value. This value needs then to be converted to a `VARCHAR` value in order to proceed the concatenation.

Comment: Ah yes, I can see my mistake. I meant `CAST(x AS varchar(10))` of course. Sorry. The point about RTRIM (or LTRIM) doing extra work still stands, though: there are no spaces to trim after converting an integer to a string in Transact-SQL, although, as I've said, it's true that `RTRIM(x)` would be much shorter to type. Sorry about all the confusion.

Comment: @AndriyM I agree, in term of performance, a better solution is to implicitly cast the integer value. I was not sure about the spaces before/after the value resulted by the conversion. I'll update my answer to show the most performant version, thank you for your remark

Answer (score 2):

The SQL Server syntax is:

```
UPPER(FORMAT(yourDate, 'MMM-yyyy'))
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL supports a number of different date formats, but does not support non-numeric based date formats. I would strongly suggest finding a method which uses one of these formats as suggested the [Microsoft SQL documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx).

Alternatively, if it is absolutely necessary that you use this format, then the following code can change any date format into the format you have requested.

```
declare @date date = '2014-01-01'
select 
case when DATEPART(mm,@date) = 1 then 'JAN'
when DATEPART(mm,@date) = 2 then 'FEB'
when DATEPART(mm,@date) = 3 then 'MAR'
when DATEPART(mm,@date) = 4 then 'APR'
when DATEPART(mm,@date) = 5 then 'MAY'
when DATEPART(mm,@date) = 6 then 'JUN'
when DATEPART(mm,@date) = 7 then 'JUL'
when DATEPART(mm,@date) = 8 then 'AUG'
when DATEPART(mm,@date) = 9 then 'SEP'
when DATEPART(mm,@date) = 10 then 'OCT'
when DATEPART(mm,@date) = 11 then 'NOV'
when DATEPART(mm,@date) = 12 then 'DEC' end 
+ '-' 
+ CONVERT(char(4),DATEPART(yy,@date)) as new_format
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like the following to format the date and compare ([**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/98b8c/6/0)):

```
SELECT * 
FROM
(
  SELECT 
    CONCAT(
      CONVERT(CHAR(3), CONVERT(DATE, MyDateField, 105), 0), 
      '-',
      DATEPART(YYYY, CONVERT(DATE, MyDateField, 105))
    ) AS DF
  FROM MyTable
) m
WHERE m.DF = 'JUN-2014';
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can use below for convert date formate.**

select left(datename(mm,[Date]),3)

 +'-' + cast( DATEPART(YYYY,[date]) as nvarchar(50))
 from  ArtistCalendar

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [**DATENAME()**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms174395.aspx) function to get the name for a given month, which can be abbreviated like so:

```
SELECT LEFT(DATENAME(mm, GETDATE()),3)  -- Output: 'Sep'
```

You can append the year using:

```
SELECT YEAR(GETDATE())
```

This should have to be converted to a string value to enable comparison with your supplied value. So you can do this:

```
SELECT LEFT(DATENAME(mm, GETDATE()),3) + '-' 
     + CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS NVARCHAR(4)) AS InputDate  -- Output: Sep-2014
```

To check equality of a supplied value, e.g. `Sep-2014`:

```
SELECT LEFT(DATENAME(mm, GETDATE()),3) + '-' 
     + CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS NVARCHAR(4)) AS InputDate,
     GETDATE() as FullDate,
     CASE WHEN LEFT(DATENAME(mm, getdate()),3) + '-' 
             + CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) as nvarchar(4)) = 'SEP-2014' 
          THEN 'True' 
          ELSE 'False' 
    END as Equality
```

**Ouptut**

```
InputDate   FullDate                 Equality
----------------------------------------------
Sep-2014    2014-09-15 14:35:57.427  True
```

**To use with your table:**

```
DECLARE @compareDate AS NVARCHAR(10)
SET @compareDate = 'Jan-2014'  -- set this

SELECT LEFT(DATENAME(mm, [YOUR_COL]),3) + '-' 
     + CAST(YEAR([YOUR_COL]) AS NVARCHAR(4)) AS InputDate,
     [YOUR_COL]as FullDate,
     CASE WHEN LEFT(DATENAME(mm, [YOUR_COL]),3) + '-' 
             + CAST(YEAR([YOUR_COL]) as nvarchar(4)) = @compareDate
          THEN 'True' 
          ELSE 'False' 
    END as Equality
From [YOUR_TABLE]
```

Just replace `[YOUR_COL]` with your date column and `[YOUR_TABLE]` with the table that holds the data column.

Comment: Be careful with this method if the application has a user-adjustable locale.  The assumption that `@MonthAbbreviation = LEFT(@MonthName,3)` doesn't hold in other languages.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle SQL
You can do something like this

```
TO_CHAR(column_name, 'MON-YYYY')
```

Comment: Please pay close attention to the tags at the bottom of the question. This question is _explicitly_ about Microsoft SQL Server. Adding an answer for a different SQL implementation is likely just to cause confusion here.